# flutter datetime how to convert it

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I have the following datetime from a database: `2022-10-02T23:10:24.736Z` I want to compare it to a datetime now and get the difference in second. Basically I have the code for it, but im not able to convert the datetime.now to the mentioned format. It tells me it has a difference of `122 minutes` but it should only be `2 minutes`..

```
 DateTime datenow = DateTime.now();
 DateTime dateFormDatabase = DateTime.parse(widget.data[widget.currIndex-1]["roundEnd"]);

print(datenow); // <---- 2022-10-01 23:22:45.522687
print(dateFormDatabase); // <--- 2022-10-01 23:25:24.736Z

var diff = dateFormDatabase.difference(datenow);
print(diff.inMinutes); // <--- 122 but it should be 2minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

The returned difference is correct. You are probably looking at different timezones here. `DateTime.now()`  returns the current date and time in your local timezone. The parsed date from your database seems to be coming in as UTC. Notice the "Z" at the end here: 2022-10-01 23:25:24.736**Z**.

If you want to visually compare them you could convert either of those to UTC/local with `toUtc` or `toLocal`

Comment: Ah okay, well I need to calculate the difference in seconds.. how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can't you use `.inSeconds` of Duration?